# node.js websocket crash after disconect (ultron/index.js:80 if (this.ee._events.hasOwnProperty(event)))

Tags: node.js, crash, disconnect

This is code :

```
 dl  = require('delivery');
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require('path');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var express    = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
function read(f) {return fs.readFileSync(f).toString();}
function include(f) {eval.apply(global, [read(f)]);}
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
function getDirectories(srcpath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory();
  });
}
function random (low, high) {
    return Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
}
function randomInt (low, high) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
}

var pkey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/httpd/ssl/maximumroulette.com.key');
var pcert = fs.readFileSync('/etc/httpd/ssl/maximumroulette_com.crt')

 var options = {
    hostname: 'maximumroulette.com',
    port: 12001,  
    key: pkey, 
    cert: pcert,
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(options.port, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + options.port);
});  


var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
// server.listen(12001);

// characterPink must exist on client part like image object 
// i will show you // I ALSO ADD NEW FIELD AND REPLACE PINK CHARACTER
// 4 is minimum for normal work
 var SYMBOLS_REEL1 ={ rez : [   "characterPink" , "characterPink" , "character4" , "character4" , "character4" ,  "character3" , "character3" , "character3" ,  "character2" ,  "character1"  ] };
 var SYMBOLS_REEL2 ={ rez : [   "characterPink" , "characterPink" , "characterPink" , "character4" , "character4" , "character4" ,  "character3" , "character3" , "character3" ,  "character2" , "character2" ,  "character1"  ] };
 var SYMBOLS_REEL3 ={ rez : [   "characterPink" , "characterPink" , "characterPink" , "character4" , "character4" , "character4" ,  "character3" , "character3" , "character3"  , "character2" ,  "character1"  ] };


    //PAYOUT 
    var characterPink = 2,
        character4 = 10, 
        character3 = 15,
        character2 = 50, 
        character1 = 200; 

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
//Networking
//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$  

 //////////////////////////
 //Validate every signal in account view
 /////////////////////////  
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {


socket.on('I_WANT', function(name){

    if (name == "FUNNYSLOT1") {

     console.log("I WANT ::::", name);
     socket.emit("CONFIG_REELS" , SYMBOLS_REEL1 ,  SYMBOLS_REEL2 , SYMBOLS_REEL3  );

    }

});

console.log("...........................................................");
console.log("GAME SERVER :CONECTED WITH NEW CLIENT !");
console.log("...........................................................");



//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ 
socket.on('SPIN', function( BET ){


var rez1 =  randomInt (0,SYMBOLS_REEL1.rez.length-1)
var rez2 =  randomInt (0,SYMBOLS_REEL1.rez.length-1)
var rez3 =  randomInt (0,SYMBOLS_REEL1.rez.length-1)

/*  
var rez3 =  7; 
var rez1 =  7;
var rez2 =  7;
 */ 
//HARDCODE RESULTS 

console.log(SYMBOLS_REEL1.rez[rez1] , "===" , SYMBOLS_REEL2.rez[rez2] , "===" ,  SYMBOLS_REEL3.rez[rez3] )
var win = 0;

 if ( ( SYMBOLS_REEL1.rez[rez1].toString() ==  SYMBOLS_REEL2.rez[rez2].toString() ) && (SYMBOLS_REEL1.rez[rez1].toString() == SYMBOLS_REEL3.rez[rez3].toString()  ) )  {


     console.log("WINNIG COMBINATION !  reel id:" , rez1 , " BET : " , BET );
     eval(" win = "+SYMBOLS_REEL1.rez[rez1]+" * BET; "); 
     console.log("WINNIG COMBINATION : for :" , rez1 , " BET : " , BET , " WIN IS :" , win);
     socket.emit("COMBINATION" , rez1 , rez2 , rez3 , win );    


 }
 else {

     socket.emit("COMBINATION" , rez1 , rez2 , rez3 , win );    

 }  

});
//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ 



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Disconnect event
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
socket.on('disconnect', function(event){
 // NO EXECUTING CODE HERE
 console.log("User disconnected no msg!" , event);
/*      if (typeof usernames[socket.email] != 'undefined'){
        console.log("User disconnected!");
        delete usernames[socket.email];
        return;
        } */

});

});
```

This is log :

> /var/maximumroulette/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/ultron/index.js:80
>         if (this.ee._events.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
>                             ^
>
> TypeError: this.ee._events.hasOwnProperty is not a function
>       at Ultron.remove (/var/maximumroulette/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/ultron/index.js:80:27)
>       at Ultron.destroy (/var/maximumroulette/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/ultron/index.js:116:8)
>       at WebSocket.cleanupWebsocketResources (/var/maximumroulette/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:851:36)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)

I update npm also node.js to the last stable version.

Any suggestion , this example works in pass time.

Comment: Could you please post the code that is not working?

Comment: SSL is valid to the 2019 y.

Comment: i reset machine i will try again...i also update Q.